# Is it possible to link to a 360 YouTube video with ReactVR?

Tags: youtube, webvr, 360-virtual-reality, react-360

In the documentation for ReactVR for [VideoPano](https://facebook.github.io/react-vr/docs/videopano.html)

it demonstrates pointing to a video in the code base.

Is it possible to link to an external link (aka Youtube)?

So instead of video.mp4, it would link to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkgYIr_LWPw&index=1&list=PL-BE7kqSgbEj44peyt5BmLK63kbDp7Rhu

```
let videoUrl = 'video.webm';
const supportedFormats = NativeModules.VideoModule.supportedFormats;
for (let i = 0; i < supportedFormats.length; i++) {
  if (supportedFormats[i] === 'mp4') {
    videoUrl = 'video.mp4';
  }
}
```

the rest of the code looks like this.

```
class WelcomeToVR extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      playerState: new MediaPlayerState({autoPlay: true, muted: true}), // init with muted, autoPlay
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
           <View>
           <VideoPano
    playerState={this.state.playerState}
  source={asset(videoUrl, {layout: 'SPHERE'})}
         />
         <VideoControl
  style={{
  height: 0.2,
          width: 4,
                 layoutOrigin: [0.5, 0.5, 0],
  transform: [{translate: [0, 0, -4]}],
}}
playerState={this.state.playerState}
```

Comment: You could try to use an embed the video: https://www.youtube.com/embed/hkgYIr_LWPw. This will give you just the video without other content.

If you need a embedded video, just left click on the video and choose "embed this video". 

Please let it know if this works.

Comment: Good idea, but when I tried it I still got 

http://localhost:8081/static_assets/https://www.youtube.com/embed/hkgYIr_LWPw 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Have you ask it here: https://github.com/facebook/react-vr

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1 *(didn't work)*

You could try to use an embed the video: https://www.youtube.com/embed/hkgYIr_LWPw. This will give you just the video without other content.

If you need a embedded video, just left click on the video and choose "embed this video" and change the source of your

```
<VideoPano playerState={this.state.playerState} source={videoUrl} />
```

Not sure if this could wok because the source code is again HTML, JS and CSS. But you could give it a try. And it didn't work

### Solution 2

Download the video using a [YouTube downloader](http://download.cnet.com/YTD/3000-2071_4-76169892.html)<sup>1</sup> or other one and use that.

```
<VideoPano playerState={this.state.playerState} 
            source={ asset(videoUrl, { layout: 'SPHERE' }) } />
```

<sup><sup>1</sup> No publicity for that tool, just the first result I've found on Google.</sup>

Comment: Good idea, but if I put a URL string, I get the following error
 "Invalid prop `source` of type `string` supplied to `VideoPano`, expected `object`."

Comment: That's because the source is made of HTML, JS and CSS. I think there is one only option left and that is download the video and use that inside your application. You could use a [YouTube downloader](http://download.cnet.com/YTD/3000-2071_4-76169892.html) for that

Comment: It doesn't look like those type of downloaders are able to download 360 videos.

Comment: Try this url: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkgYIr_LWPw. This url not not a video from a playlist

Answer (score 0):

YouTube intentionally chooses to obfuscate the direct links to their video files. Linking the embedded player isn't a solution since that thing's a mini web app with streaming logic, not an actual video file.

There's a pretty good write-up on how you could get around that here [How do all of these “Save video from YouTube” services work?](https://superuser.com/questions/773719/how-do-all-of-these-save-video-from-youtube-services-work) (probably against their Terms and Conditions though).

It is possible, however, to link to an external video URL, here's how:

1. Pick a random 3D 360 YouTube video, [like this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3aRdtcsA7LI)
2. Download it, I used [savefrom.net](https://en.savefrom.net/1-how-to-download-youtube-video/) but there are many others and host it somewhere `http://YOURDOMAIN/YOURVIDEO.mp4`
3. Render a `<VideoPano />` in your scene/view

   ```
   <VideoPano source={{
     uri: 'http://YOURDOMAIN/YOURVIDEO.mp4',
     stereo: 'BOTTOM_TOP_3D' // this is specific to YouTube 3D videos
   }} />
   ```

https://facebook.github.io/react-vr/docs/videopano.html