# Is it possible to link to external images / videos with React-VR?

Tags: youtube, webvr, react-360

According to the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-vr/docs), there doesn't seem to be any examples of using external images or external videos (i.e. from YouTube).

I was wondering if anyone knew if it was possible (like this)

```
<Video style={{
        width: 3.0,
        height:2.0,
        transform: [{translate: [0, 4, 5]},  {rotateY : 180} ],
        }} source={{uri: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vPCoxAlfFsw'}} />
```

Comment: Have you ask it here: https://github.com/facebook/react-vr

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to link to a 360 YouTube video with ReactVR?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43576301/is-it-possible-to-link-to-a-360-youtube-video-with-reactvr)

Answer (score 0):

MediaPlayerState in react vr home page