# How to link to external and internal pages in React-VR?

Tags: webvr, react-360

I would like the ability for the user to click a button using the React-VR cursor and be able to go to external and internal pages like this

```
  onEnter={() => Linking.openURL("https://www.google.com").catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err))}
```

or

```
onEnter={() => Linking.openURL("paris.vr.js").catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err))}
```

But I'm getting the following error 
"Cannot read property 'openURL' of undefined"

Can someone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to link to external images / videos with React-VR?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43748706/is-it-possible-to-link-to-external-images-videos-with-react-vr)

Comment: Nope, this isn't trying to embed images or videos. This question has to do with allowing the user to click to other pages